# Is there any way to open Battery Usage of an application (Intent)?

Tags: android

I have been seeing how I can open the Battery Manager of my application (not another) directly since one attempt, I have achieved results but they are not correct for my purpose.

This is the activity that I want to open:

[image]

I can open App Info with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(intent);
```

I am not looking for "BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" because it violates google play policies:

Note: Google Play policies prohibit apps from requesting direct exemption from Power Management features in Android 6.0+ (Doze and App Standby) unless the core function of the app is adversely affected.

Comment: check below answer is it working?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent powerUsageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(powerUsageIntent, 0);
// check that the Battery app exists on this device
if(resolveInfo != null){
    startActivity(powerUsageIntent);
}
```

Comment: Not working, this carries to "Battery". This is what I try to open: Settings -> Apps -> [App Name] -> Battery